# Undefined offset when inserting data with Guzzle Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

Im inserting data from an third party api to my database by using Guzzle. Everything seems to be fine, until one of this fields does not exist from the api. It comes with the error: "UNDEFINED OFFSET", so im asuming that is the problem.
This is my command schedule:

```
        $client = new Client(['headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json']]); 
        $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://example.com/api/apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
        $data = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(),true);
        $events = $data['Data'];

        foreach($events as $item)
        {
                        DB::table('apidata')->updateOrInsert([
                'matchID'=>$item['matchID']],
                [
                'matchID'=>$item['matchID'] ?? null,
                'startTime'=>date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($item['startTime'])) ?? null,
                'timeLive'=>$item['timeLive'] ?? null,
                'homeTeam'=>$item['homeTeamInfo']['homeTeam'] ?? null,
                'homeGoals' =>$item['homeTeamInfo']['homeGoals'] ?? null,
                'awayGoals'=>$item['awayTeamInfo']['awayGoals'] ?? null,
                'awayTeam'=>$item['awayTeamInfo']['awayTeam'] ?? null,
```

So what is the best way to avoid the "UNDEFINED OFFSET" error in case the api comes with an non existing field?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us updateOrInsert method body along with passed arguments

Comment: @RonnyKid need more information. Can you post the trace of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you use the `startTime` element does not cater for the value not being found.  The `?? null` bit is only used after you try and convert it to a time and then a date...

```
'startTime'=>date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($item['startTime'])) ?? null,
```

In this case you may be better off using the old method of `isset()`...

```
'startTime'=>isset($item['startTime']) ?date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($item['startTime'])) 
                                        : null,
```

Same with...

```
bcdiv($item['odds'][0]['regular'][0]['odds'][0]['decimalValue'],1,2) ?? null
```

...

```
isset($item['odds'][0]['regular'][0]['odds'][0]['decimalValue']) ?
       bcdiv($item['odds'][0]['regular'][0]['odds'][0]['decimalValue'],1,2) 
      : null
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get ```Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)``` when i put the isset method.

Comment: If you look at the code in the answer, it is used as in `isset($item['startTime'])`.

Comment: I see. but the problem happens with this field ```bcdiv($item['odds'][0]['regular'][0]['odds'][0]['decimalValue'],1,2) ?? null,```. What is the best way to isset it?

Comment: In the same way `isset($item['odds'][0]['regular'][0]['odds'][0]['decimalValue'])`

Comment: The problem using `bcdiv($a,1,2)??null` is that `bcdiv()` will try and use the value for the calculation and cause the error, you could also use `bcdiv($a??1,1,2)` if you wanted to set it to something valid.  But as you seem to want empty values to be null, I'm not sure if you could do this without using `isset()`.

Comment: This field of the api can come null and sometimes this field does not exist. What do you suggest to avoid any kind of error? Also can you be more detailed about the bcdiv function? Should i use it there?

Comment: If you want to test for null as well - use `!empty()` instead of `isset()`.  The bcdiv() was only an example of how it can be used, nothing wrong with using it.

Answer (score 1):

For every field you are inserting, add a check whether it is set or not..

```
DB::table('apidata')->updateOrInsert([
            'matchID'=>$item['matchID']],
            [
            'matchID'=>isset($item['matchID']) ? $item['matchID'] : '',
            'startTime'=>isset($item['startTime']) ? date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($item['startTime'])) : '',
            'timeLive'=>isset($item['timeLive']) ? $item['timeLive'] : '',
            'homeTeam'=>isset($item['homeTeamInfo']['homeTeam']) ? $item['homeTeamInfo']['homeTeam'] : '',
            'homeGoals' =>isset($item['homeTeamInfo']['homeGoals']) ? $item['homeTeamInfo']['homeGoals'] : '',
            'awayGoals'=>isset($item['awayTeamInfo']['awayGoals']) ? $item['awayTeamInfo']['awayGoals'] : '',
            'awayTeam'=>isset($item['awayTeamInfo']['awayTeam']) ? $item['awayTeamInfo']['awayTeam'] : '',
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I suppose this way is also for the null field also, is this correct?

Comment: yeah..You can replace `isset()` with `!empty()` for testing null value..It will work.